# Select value from JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

How to select data from bellow JSON code?

```
"response": {
"status": 1,
"httpStatus": 200,
"data": [
{
"offer_id": "8000",
"countries": {
"SG": {
"id": "702",
"code": "SG",
"name": "Singapore",
"regions": []
}
}
```

How could I select the words SG and SINGAPORE

Comment: is this your json? the part you have post is invalid

Comment: This just a part of my code

Comment: Since you're dealing with arrays and objects which appear to be designed to hold a variable number of items: **you loop.**

Comment: I am asking whether the structure you post is object or objects in array

Comment: Take a look at [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: decode the json, then it's just a php data structure and you access it like you would any **OTHER** php data structure. ignore the fact that it's json. treat json like wrapping paper around a present. rip of the wrapping paper and throw it away.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the json_decode function from php. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

For exemple :

```
<?php
$json = '{"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": [{
        "offer_id": "8000",
        "countries": {
            "SG": {
                "id": "702",
                "code": "SG",
                "name": "Singapore",
                "regions": []
            }
        }
    }]
}}';
$decode = json_decode($json);
var_dump($decode->response->data[0]->countries->SG->name);
```

Comment: Why did you change the structure of his data?  In the question, `data` was an array.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Cause his JSON was incorrect

Comment: Yes, he is missing an opening `{` and a bunch of closing `}`/`]`, but why did you change `data` from an array to an object?

Comment: Cause their were both `[` and `{` so i guess it was a mistake.

Comment: I updated your answer with the fixed/corrected data structure.

Comment: Thanks @RocketHazmat :)

Comment: This is a misleading answer, since supposedly you'd want to loop through `data`, and probably though `countries` as well, instead of just accessing the *first* item. Probably `SG` as a key is unknown as well.